# Smartsheet API get_sheet (Python) filters not working

Tags: smartsheet-api

I'm using Python 3.52 , Smartsheet API SDK 2.0.10.

The get_sheet (in sheets.py) has three 'filters' which are lists of integers for

1. row_numbers,
2. column_ids, and
3. row_ids.

I can get none of them to work, together or separately.
For example,

```
row_numbers = [2, 13]
sheet = smartsheet.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id, row_numbers)
for row in sheet.rows:
    print(row.row_number)
```

returns all of the rows, not just 2 and 13.
Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reputation won't let me comment yet, but Steve W is on the right track.

See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls for a description of how Python assigns arguments to parameters list. In your example `row_numbers` is being assigned to the `include` parameter. To do what you want you'll have to use a combination of positional(`sheet_id`) and keyword(`row_numbers`) arguments. All other arguments will use defaults as specified by function definition.

This code works as expected, returning the 2nd and 13th rows in the sheet:

```
row_numbers=[2,13]
sheet = smartsheet.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id, row_numbers=row_numbers)
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had done that when trying 2 or 3 of the filters, but I must have been wrong. Not the first time.

Answer (score 1):

The full method signature is `get_sheet(sheet_id, include=None, exclude=None, row_ids=None, row_numbers=None, column_ids=None, page_size=100, page=1)`

See [docs](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/smartsheet-python-sdk/smartsheet.html?highlight=get_sheet#smartsheet.sheets.Sheets.get_sheet)

So in your case you'd need something like `smartsheet.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id, None, None, None, row_numbers )`

Comment: I don't believe that is true. Any argument that has a default value does not need to be passed. In addition, the definition is not using positional arguments (requiring *).

Comment: In your example, how would python know that you expect your list to be used as the value for the 5th parameter? (Also, my examples works as expected)

Comment: @SteveWeil how do you get all rows? it seems that even though the documentation says it default calls all the rows, this is not the case. Is there a way to reference the total number of rows from the sheet object? Or somehow dynamically denote the row length of the sheetz?

Comment: @Robert - As per the docs, we default to a page size of 100 rows unless you specify otherwise. Please post a new question if you want to discus

Comment: @SteveWeil ended up figuring it out - but one last question, how would the formatting look like when filtering by certain columns/filtering by column value?